# $\beta = b_i y^i$ be a one form and $s_{ij} =\frac{1}{2} (b_{i:j} - b_{j:i} )$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\beta = b_i y^i$  be a one form and $s_{ij} =\frac{1}{2} (b_{i:j} - b_{j:i} )$, where : is the covarient differentiation with respect to Levi- Civita Connection. Then what is the value of $(s_{ij})_{y^k}$ and $(s^i_0)_{y^k}$? 
Here suffix denote the partial differentiation w.r.t $y^k$?

Comment: In general $(s_{ij})_{y^k}$ is not tensorial and should have no meaning.